# Convergent Sequence Analysis

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $(a_n)\to a$ with $a \in \mathbb R$

If $A \leq a_n \leq B$ then $A \leq a \leq B$

Proof:

Consider the sequences $(b_n)=A$ and $(c_n) = B$

Thus $(b_n)\to A$ & $(c_n)\to B$

Noting $(b_n) \leq(a_n)\leq(c_n) $ $\forall n \in \mathbb N$

Thus $A \leq a \leq B$

$\blacksquare$
is this a valid proof? thanks.

Comment: And your question?

Comment: The proof is ok if you really can use the fact that if $a_n\to a$, $b_n\to b$ and $a_n\leq b_n$ for all $n$ then $a\leq b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a valid proof. You proved your statement only for two specific sequences, not in the general case.

Suppose that $a<A$. Take $\varepsilon=A-a$. There is a natural $N$ such that$$n\geqslant N\implies\lvert a_n-a\rvert<\varepsilon=A-a.$$But then$$a_N-a\leqslant\lvert a_N-a\rvert<A-A$$and therefore $a_N<A$, which is a contradiction.

By a similar argument, you can't have $a>B$.

Comment: I'm failing to see your contradiction, you're saying that $a_N <A$ is a contradiction yet it agrees with your supposition that $a < A$

Comment: It contradicts the hypothesis that$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):A\leqslant a_n\leqslant B.$$

Comment: Ah that makes sense, great!